# Using require on a .json file will return an empty array if file is being required by another function at the same time

Tags: json, node.js, asynchronous

I don't have much experience with node but I've run into a pitfall when running code that handles I/O (a simplification of my code):

I have `data.json` which contains `['foo','bar']` with many functions that read and parse this file like so:

```
// foo.js
module.exports = function() {
  // do stuff
  var data = require("path/to/data.json");
  return data;

};

// bar.js
module.exports = function() {
  // do stuff
  var data = require("path/to/data.json");
  return data;
};
```

However when I call them:

```
// main.js
var foo = require('foo');
var bar = require('bar');

console.log(foo()); // gives ['foo','bar']
console.log(bar()); // gives []
```

I suspect while `foo` is reading `data.json`, it "locks" the file then preventing `bar` from reading it, but I'm not sure why `bar` still returns an empty array instead of undefined.

Using `require` to read a json file was a bad idea as I have them littered throughout my entire codebase. Is there an easy fix for something like this? What would be the preferred method of reading json files knowing that at any given moment that file might be accessed by another function?

Answer (score 1):

As we know, `require()` will always cache the content of the loaded module (or file, in this case). The next time require() is called again, it will restore it from the cache instead of reading it again.

In your case, you was reading the file once for each `foo.js` and `bar.js`. Here, `foo` had changed a value from the JSON, and because it’s content was cached by require(), the changed value was loaded into `bar`, in which I was expecting it to be the original value. But, since foo already read it till end, you are at EOF. So, `bar` returns empty array [there is nothing to read, but file is valid].

**SOLUTION:**
Stick with `fs` module when reading JSON files.